# How to measure chainring / cog wear?

Tags: maintenance, chainring, sprocket

Other than attempting to estimate whether a chainring or cog is worn and needs replaced by eyballing it, is there any way to **measure** the wear on chainrings or cassette cogs so you can determine whether they should be replaced?  What tools can be used to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes.  Bike shops have a gauge for measuring cog wear, and I think you can buy one from Park Tools.  (A little pricy, though, if I recall.)  But it's generally possible to tell when a cog is too worn by visual inspection and how it performs.

Comment: Rohloff makes one - the Rohloff HG-Check.

Comment: I've got one of these Rohloff gauges, and its pretty useless.  Boils down to "Does a chain slip?" then its worn out.

Answer (score 4):

Because there exist so many cassette styles and tooth profiles, no universal tool for measuring cassette wear exists.

One good advice to assist visual inspection is this. We all have our favorite speeds. Compare the most worn 2-3 cogs with the rest. If their profile is very different, the cassete is probably worn. The video documents how to do that.

There are many variables in determining whether you have a worn chainring or cassette. Visual inspection helps and noting the kilometres racked up should also help.

If you have set up your mech's correctly you will know you have wear when your chain starts to skip, especially under load. Visual inspection should then confirm your wear.

Park Tools do a CHAIN wear tool [CC-2] but that will not determine cassette or chainring wear.  When replacing a cassette you should always replace the chain. Worn chains will reduce the life of cassettes and chainrings considerable due to the chain being worn to the form of the previous cassette/chainring.

Here is a video of the pro's confirming the above:

Hope this helps.

Comment: As stated in the comments to the question, tools for measuring sprocket wear exist. The visual check is usually sufficient though.

Comment: I have personally seen a chainring wear measuring tool being used, by a reputable bike mechanic.

Comment: Yea, that 'mechanic' also had a tyre-wear tool. Never managed to buy one though or obtain the part number from Park Tools.

Comment: The controversial statement "No cassette wear tool exists" is extracted from the video. I edited the sentence a little and added a bit more context. The video is awesome, watch it!

Comment: I'm wondering what good a tire wear tool would do on a bike, given that many tires are essentially bald by design.  I've never seen one.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Presumably the tyre wear tool would indicate flat spotting. It would have a variable-radius curved profile that should sit snugly around a properly-inflated new tyre. Worn tyres would be "squared off" and gaps would be visible. But I agree, it seems like a waste of time...

Comment: @headeronly - I have doubts whether that could work, given the natural irregularities in the average tire, uneven mounting, out-of-round rims, etc.  It might work to dismount the tire and gauge it's thickness, but that's a lot of work when you can get the same info by partially deflating the tire and seeing how soft it is in the middle.

Answer (score 4):

There are tools such as the [Rohloff HG-check](https://www.rohloff.de/en/products/tools/) for measuring cassette wear.

And of course there is visual inspection and also how it rides and indexes, particularly under heavy load (when it will usually slip if worn).

Comment: @styrofoamfly Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Not an easy solution, but you can use a photocopier to measure wear on chainrings.  This doesn't tend to work with cassettes cos they're thicker.

First, remove the worn chainring from the bike, and clean it well to keep oils off the copier's glass and undercover.  Then photocopy it at 1:1 size.

Flip the chainring and lay it on top of your copy, so that the bolt holes align.  There will be at least one position where the teeth line up.

Then trace around the rear of a tooth.  Remove chainring and visually compare the overlaps, and then use a caliper to measure the differences for a numeric result.

Comment: One could make copies of the sprockets when new and use those later to track wear.

Comment: I think this great idea works best when cogs are symmetrical (teeth have symmetrical profile). For multi speed cogs is common that teeth have slanted profile when new to aid in gear shifts. For that situation Argenti's solution is best, but it requires action way before the measurement is needed.

Answer (score 1):

[ANSI standards for industrial chains](http://www.globalspec.com/learnmore/mechanical_components/chains_sprockets/sprockets_roller_chain_english) are that a sprocket should be replaced when

> the depth of the erosion along the tooth (x) has reached a value equal to 10 percent of the tooth width (Y) across the pitch diameter (PCD)

This would roughly translate into 0.5 mm, probably impossible to measure while the cassette is on the wheel.

A better way is to compare your old sprockets to new ones, when you clean your ageing cassette. Keeping in mind that sprocket wear is inversely proportional to the cog count, I'd suggest focusing on the 13T-15T-17T (or so) sprockets. Put the old sprocket on top of a new one (you have to purchase a replacement anyway, so buy one as a reference until the old one is worn) and inspect visually to appreciate the amount of wear at the back of the cog.

Answer (score 0):

A few distinct camps appear here, regarding how and whether it is feasible to adequately measure cassette cog and chainring wear. The Rohloff tool looks to be basically an eight link chain bit attached to a small lever arm with the short end effectively adding another link-lengthed arm that is positioned so as to provide force on the chain segment. I would think this is little different, really, from a regular cassette sprocket tool, which might be finagled into position to check the same concept, as long as the chain portion is not old and worn.
  As shown with chain wear tools, there are often other methods that indirectly measure things like wear, by indirect but sufficiently accurate means for normal use. Wrapping a section of chain around a suspect cog and applying tension should be fairly easy to do, and the principle that a worn cog will not allow more than five pins to move in and out without binding, seems crude, yet the concept automatically incorporates the wear into something observable and apparent, while measuring tiny surface changes is exceedingly tedious and prone to error. http://uniortools.com sells their version with a regular bit of HG chain used as the checking segment, so there is nothing magical or special about the Rohloff, or the concept itself. In practice, I've seen folks intentionally ride chains and cogsets about twenty years past due, and while they had to fight chain hop and shifting issues, they could still ride the bike. The fear over a calamitous event is likely a waste of energy; if you regularly clean and lube chains, replace before the wear point is passed, every five to ten years you might eventually reach a point where a new chain starts misbehaving on an older cassette, when pedaling hard. Just replace your cassette then, before putting too many miles on the new chain, and you're good for another five to ten years. Do not overthink the problem.

Comment: I've got the rohloff cassette tool and TBH its utterly useless.  Maybe I just lack the touch.

Answer (score -1):

I'll just comment on chainrings, since the other responders have already provided good guidelines regarding rear cogsets. My ways of "measuring" chainring wear, without any tool, would be to first wrap a new chain around the suspect ring, then inspect it carefully, to see if the chain sits tight in the bottom of the gap between the teeth (good, so far), or if it appears as if it "lifts" out of the gap (not so good). A worn ring will usually have an irregular, asymmetrical appearance. You will see that the tips of each tooth look as if they are beginning to look sharp & pointy, and the ends of the teeth will have lost some of the nice, square edges where they were originally machined & finished.

The worst effect of a worn-out chain is that it stretches over time with use, and so the pivot bushings are no longer correctly spaced at 1/2-inch intervals. This is what causes the eventual failure of the teeth to grip the chain. The chain will tend to "ride high" on the teeth.

Perhaps the best way to see if your rings are really all that worn is to compare them visually to a new ring of the same brand. Bring your crank to a bike shop and look around. Some types of rings feature somewhat-odd tooth profiles. Do a careful comparison of your rings with some new ones and pay particular attention to the leading edge of each tooth, where it does the work of pulling the chain along. You'll almost certainly see some wear here.

Another way of checking is by merely giving the ring a good cleaning. Does the black gunk built up on the teeth come off easily, or is it practically ground into the metal? Do the teeth have good, square edges, or do they seem as if they were rounded over? Is there a semblance of a flat end on each tooth, or do they look like shark's teeth? Are the teeth finger-friendly, or are they riddled with sharp burrs ?

Compare the way a new chain will stay close to the rings of a new bike when you attempt to lift a section of the chain up and away from the teeth. It should only lift a tiny amount. If the chain can lift off the ring excessively, then it's no longer fully seating between the teeth during rides, and this will cause wear. This is because a stretched chain will ride near the tops of the (worn) teeth, and will chew into the leading side of each tooth. The chain's contact region is being concentrated on a too-small area of each tooth.

Finally, the last one I can think of is to try moving the chain lengthwise, back-and-forth on the ring. A worn ring will allow some movement, while a new ring & chain will seem stuck together. In the end, it's a matter of cost, convenience, and whatever you deem as acceptable ride quality, and you'll have to be the one to make the decision. It may be seen as the right opportunity to replace & upgrade, or it may be the sound of the death knell, and you may move on to another bike entirely. Or, you may find that your rings still have a lot of life left in them. A lot of it depends on the worth of the bike itself.

I'll assume we're asking this question because we have a bike that we love & wish to preserve. But a lesser ride may not be worth the investment in new components. The point I hope to make overall is that it's not usually an easy thing to determine, and you need to use your best judgment. These are most of the guidelines I've used in my 47 years of bike repairs. Hope this helps.

Comment: This wall of text is really hard to read -- please could you edit some paragraph breaks into it? Also, the parts of it I looked at don't seem to answer the actual question, which is specifically about whether it's possible to _measure_ cog wear. You seem to be giving lots of (probably good!) advice about how to _judge_ whether the cogs are worn and about whether or not they're worth replacing, but that's not what the question actuall yasks.

Comment: Welcome to SE Bicycles.  You obviously have a wealth of experience to share and we appreciate that.  Please have a browse through the [tour] to learn how SE is a bit different to most chatty web forums - the answers have to answer the question and then expand on it.    Every single point you make is completely correct, but nothing gives a numerical measurement for wear, which is the question.

Comment: None of the sprocket tools (Rohloff, Unior, etc.) provide any numerical measurements. Who would use such numbers? Race teams? Continental tourists? Bike shops? Maybe...nobody? Folks, you aren't going to find an answer, in mm, inches, or a percentage, but trust me, it's okay! You will never need any such answer. If you are losing sleep over this, contact a manufacturer, and see if they will provide you with a blueprint of a ring or a cog. Then, you're on your own. Perhaps there are good, practical reasons why we don't BOTHER to measure cables for stretch, frames for flex, or saddles for "sag".

Comment: @RandolphPatterson you make a good point "numerical measurements are hard"  but a percentage of wear should be possible.  When a thing needs changing without question, its 100% worn and U/S.  When its new its 0% worn.  OP probably wants to know how close they are to requiring replacement.  This could be a question that has no single good answer.

Answer (score -2):

Cassettes are harder to measure.  For example they adjust spacing for IG (Interactive Glide).

Chain is something you can easily measure. 
And it is the cheapest and easiest component of the drive train to replace.
A stretched chain will increase the wear on cassette and chain ring.

- Measure chain
- Replace chain when stretched
- For sure replace cassette when chain jumps on a new chain
  Or a visual inspection of the cassette - compare it to picture or if you have a replacement on hand compare it to the new.
- Chain ring
  Visual inspection is a good guide.  If the teeth are pointed it is worn.

Cheap it (optional) 
At most you are gong to get 3 chains.
In the 3rd chain wait for it to skip and replace chain, cassette, and chain ring. 
As Hick commented a chain ring will typically last two cassettes so only cheap it when you know the chain ring is also on its last leg.

Comment: Generally you're going to need 2-3 changes of the rear cluster before the rings need changing, and then likely only one or two rings need changing.

Comment: Down vote care to comment?

Comment: You probably got downvoted for not answering the question at all, which is very clearly about measuring the tooth wear of sprockets, not about measuring chains, or other methods of scheduling drive component replacement. Also, "wait for it to skip" is the sort of approach you may be able to specifically avoid by inspecting and measuring. Your first chain slip may occur in a situation when it is inconvenient to tend bike maintenance, like in the middle of a trek.

Comment: @kax But there is no good way to measure cassette so I attempted to address what could be measured. I tired to fix the answer.  You think I should just delete it?